# Connect to SQLite frome Activity class

Tags: sqlite

I created some tables in SQlite Database Browser, but I don't know how to connect to them from java class. I have searched for this problem but some tutorial only talk about the way to connect with database that have created from java class. So can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: I assume this is for Android.  Is your problem setting up the Java database code or where to put the database?

Comment: My problem is: how to connect to database in SQLite Database Browser. For example, in java we have : DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"; - the path to connect to MySQL database. But in adroid I ditn't find any solution like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the tutorials you found don't help, Lars Vogel has a good Android SQLite tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html.

Since you already have a database, make sure your Android database code references the same columns and put your .db file in `/data/data/com.example.app/databases` on your Android device, where `com.example.app` is your application name.  In your class derived from `SQLiteOpenHelper`, the database name (e.g., mydb.db) is passed to the parent constructor:

```
class MyDatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MyDatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

When you want a handle to the database, you'll call

```
SQLiteDatabase db = myDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase()
```

or

```
SQLiteDatabase db = myDatabaseOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried and my project worked well.